# Edit values within dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
TestDict = {'Group1': 'Crew 1', 'Group2': 'Crew 2', 'Group3': 'Crew 3'}
```

And I'd like to edit the `value` in the dictionary to have this desired output

```
{'Group1': 'Group1_Crew_1', 'Group2': 'Group2_Crew_2', 'Group3': 'Group3_Crew_3'}
```

So in the above, the `key` is now a part of the `value` and the space have been replaced with `_`

So far I've only tried to tackle appending the key to the value with

```
for key, value in TestDict.items():
    newDict = {key: key + "_" + value for key in TestDict}
```

Problematically, this outputs in the proper dictionary, however, all of the values are `Group3_Crew 3`. I'm not sure how to navigate this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

Create a new dictionary and update it content:

```
newDict = {}
for key, value in TestDict.items():
    newDict[key] = key + "_" + value.replace(" ", "_")
```

or use a dict comprehension:

```
newdDict = {key: key + "_" + value.replace(" ", "_") for key in TestDict}
```

You were like mixing both concepts.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems.

Firstly, you're iterating over TestDict twice, where you only need to do so once.  You're recreating an entire new version of newDict each time through the loop and, after you're done, you're only seeing the last one created.

Use *either*

```
 newDict = {} 
 for key, value in TestDict.items():
     newDict[key] = key + "_" + value
```

or

```
 newDict = {key: key + "_" + value for key, value in TestDict.items()}
```

but don't combine both.

(The results you're seeing are because you're getting a new `key` in each inner iteration, but only a single `value` from the outer iteration.)

Also, you're not replacing spaces with underscores, which you would do by replacing `value` with `value.replace(' ', '_')` in either version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
{k: k+'_'+v.replace(' ', '_') for k, v in TestDict.items()}
```